# Find $b_n$ independent of $x$ satisfying $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{x^{n+1}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

I am looking for non-trivial real coefficients $b_n$ independent of $x$ satisfying:$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{x^{n+1}}=0$$

or prove that $b_n=0$ for every $n=0,1,2...$

Note that $b_n$ must be independent of $x$ otherwise it is not difficult to construct such $b_n$ dependent of $x$ and satisfying above.

Edit: $x$ is a given fixed but arbitrary natural number.

Comment: Take $x\to \infty$. The dominating term is $b_0/x$ so $b_0$ has to be zero. Repeat!

Comment: @Winther  $x$ is a fixed natural number. What do you mean by taking it to infinity. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: As written it looks like you intend this to hold for all $x$. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to say $b_n$ does not depend on $x$. Say if $x = 2$ what does it mean for $b_n$ to not depend on $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\sum b_n y^{n}=0$ for all $ y \neq 0$. By elementary complex analysis, $b_n=0$ for all $n$. [ The series represents an analytic function (because convergence for all $y \neq 0$ is assumed) and the zeros of this analytic function have a limit point].